# Why does Scala regexp work differently in pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have a simple regular expression `val emailRegex = "\\w+@\\w+\\.\\w+".r` that matches simple emails (not for production, of course:). When I run the following code:

```
println(email match {
  case emailRegex(_) => "cool"
  case _ => "not cool"
})

printlnemailRegex.pattern.matcher(email).matches())
```

It prints `not cool` and `true`. Adding anchors doesn't help either: `"^\\w+@\\w+\\.\\w+$".r` gives the same result. But when I add parentheses `"(\\w+@\\w+\\.\\w+)".r` it prints `cool` and `true`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6):

The number of arguments to a regex pattern should match the number of capturing group in the regex. Your regex does not have any capturing groups, so there should be zero arguments:

```
println(email match {
  case emailRegex() => "cool"
  case _ => "not cool"
})

printlnemailRegex.pattern.matcher(email).matches())
```

Answer (score 5):

Because pattern matching with a regex is about capturing regex groups:

```
val email = "foo@foo.com"
val slightyDifferentEmailRegex = "(\\w+)@\\w+\\.\\w+".r // just add a group with two brackets
println(email match {
  case slightyDifferentEmailRegex(g) => "cool" + s" and here's the captured group: $g"
  case _ => "not cool"
})
```

prints:

> cool and here's the captured group: foo

Comment: Don't hesitate to check out @sepp2k answer which has a pretty complementary way of explaining what's happening.